# Date on ls command

Tags: osx, ls, date, iso

Today I saw that the `ls -l` command does not display the date a file was created. In summary, I downloaded an iso today and in the `ls -l` I have `Mar 14 2015` !

Why is that? The file was created today on my computer, no?

Comment: I would advise making a question at a time.

Comment: How did you download the ISO file?

Comment: Is the win 8.1 from the windows site

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in what the ISO is. I would like to know [_how_ you downloaded it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/463054/edit). (What command or process? Exactly.)

Answer (score 1):

so one can set the time of a file to anything one wants, many copy/download tools permit keeping the original date (so you know when the file was made or edited which is typically more useful then when you downloaded or copied it) there is creation, modification, and access time, but if you want to change the file time you can `touch $file`

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System

colors are for access rights

```
ls -hal
```

Comment: There is no creation time, only access, modify, and change.  Touch will update the modify time.

Comment: Yes, but 2015 is modified or change? I had it downloaded with wget. So the date in the ls it corresponds to what?

Comment: It's not to see the files in color, it's to understand what the colors correspond to. Because one of the two iso has a different color.

Comment: @The33Coder: the date in ls will be the modify time.  It's likely that is when the file was last modified by its creator.

Comment: @Jesse_b are you sure that Mac OSX doesn't have creation time?

Comment: @roaima: mine doesn't.  I run macos though.

Comment: @Jesse_b I'll have to look at my Air tomorrow. However, [this link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) seems to suggest Creation time exists as a separate entity to Modification time

Comment: Well I do show created time in the GUI but I can't find it in the terminal with `stat` so I'm fairly certain `ls -l` is showing modify as it is on any other system.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "creation date" is most Unix file systems. And when it exists it is called a "birth date".

The date referred to by "c" is command parameters is not the "creation" date but the "change" date. While the "modification" date is about the file contents (like in Windows, for instance), the "change" date is about the "container" (renamed, moved, attributes changed, etc...).